Transform cross tabs table into detailed list view
I'm trying to take the first table in the linked sample sheet below and transform it into the formatting of the second table in that same sheet, which is more of a list view. Here is a sample sheet with this data.
I was thinking I could use a query or filters but can't figure out how to do so successfully, incorporating all desired information into the output table. I want to only include details in the output table, when the hire need is greater than 0.
Thanks in advance!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. In addition, the tag description for [tag:google-sheets] says specifically not to use an image or link to the sheet, but to provide a text table instead. Please [edit] your question to comply with this guidance. Thanks.

You can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY( 
   SPLIT(TOCOL(C4:N4&"|"&C5:N5&"|"&B8:B12&"|"&C6:N6&"|"&C7:N7&"|"&C8:N12),"|"),
   "where 0<Col6"))

